# How to export Selenium IDE Test Suite in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-ide

I know how to export Test case in python from Selenium IDE. But I wonder Is it possible to export Test Suite in python?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported in the core Selenium IDE itself (yet), but this add-on will let you export all the test cases in a suite in one go:

- [Selenium Test Suite Batch Converter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/test-suite-batch-converter-sel/) (Firefox add-on by Samit Badle)

Answer (score -2):

You can export Selenium IDE Test Suite in Python like the following steps:

1. Record the series of actions to test which you would like to export from the Selenium IDE. This is the "test suite" in which actions that evoke certain behaviors are saved by Selenium to repeat on command.
2. In the menu bar, click "Options," then "Format," then "Python."
3. Save the test under the name "test one," and then save the Python test suite as "test_one.py". The Python script will represent the actions in test suite in Python code.

Read more : http://www.ehow.com/how_12188004_export-python-test-suite-selenium.html

Comment: The procedure you described is for exporting one only test to Python, not a Test Suite. In addition, I am unable to access the article you linked. The problem mentioned above is about exporting a set of tests which will all run together, one after another. See the related export issue in the following [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/WYlhIHnVf7I)

Comment: link leads to an article titled "How to Convert MATLAB Scripts to Python"